Manga where the bespectacled main character meets a porter girl and gets trapped in a cave fighting a monster
I know bits and pieces, so bear with me.
The main character (MC) has black hair, bad eyesight, and wears glasses. He meets this porter girl who I think goes on about wanting to be strong and I think he says he’ll help. Another thing I remember is that the MC and the porter girl are in a cave fighting a monster and he tells her to leave and get help; he stays behind but I think the cave caves in and his glasses break. I think he fights for a long time and all he’s thinking about is seeing a human again. By the way, he’s really strong and looks like the MC from Wistoria, kinda.

Was this full colour or mostly black & white? And what sort of time period/world was the story set in?

All black & white. As for time period no idea.

Is this My Blade Will Lead the Way! Abandoned in a Labyrinth as a Directionally Challenged S-Rank Swordsman...?

The swordsman, Jir, had just joined a well-known S-rank party when he finds himself stranded all alone in the hardest labyrinth. Normally, there's no way to survive such a situation other than to wait for rescue. Relying on nothing but his heroic sword skills, Jir decides to escape on his own! "Heh! You're all bark and no bite, Labyrinth!" he boldly declares. Due to his extremely poor sense of direction, he's completely unaware that he's headed towards the deepest level where the labyrinth boss awaits!!

The protagonist, Jir, is a black-haired, bespectacled swordsman who was recently hired to help an S-ranked party of adventurers raid a labyrinth.
He notices the leader of the party, Godach, being rude to a rookie support member and baggage handler for the party, Kraha, and stands up for her. Shortly afterwards, she asks Jir how she can become stronger, and he offers to teach her how to sword fight.



In chapter 2, Jir is fighting the third floor boss in the labyrinth and Godach unleashes an attack that causes both Jir and the boss to fall through the floor. Jir's glasses also break, leaving him unable to see clearly.
In chapter 3, Godach orders his party to withdraw from the labyrinth, abandoning Jir, despite Kraha's protests.
In chapter 4, Jir has been trapped in the labyrinth for three months and his mental health is suffering. He then encounters a saintess, but can't see her clearly without his glasses, and is overjoyed when he realises she's a person rather than another monster.




Yup this is it thanks.

@Itachistan - If this answer is correct, please consider marking it as accepted by clicking on the grey check mark near the top-left corner of the answer. It's this site's way of formally indicating that a query has been solved to the querent's satisfaction.
